# LDAP filter for searching students

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am fairly new to LDAP and AD. I want to create an LDAP filter to show all the students in the AD. But the problem is that the students are in different BASE DN:

```
OU=STUDENTS,OU=USERS,OU=SOE,OU=FOAE,OU=UNIVERSITY,DC=sepang
OU=STUDENTS,OU=USERS,OU=SOMLC,OU=FOAE,OU=UNIVERSITY,DC=sepang
OU=STUDENTS,OU=USERS,OU=SOCS,OU=FOS,OU=UNIVERSITY,DC=sepang
```

i.e for each student it is like

```
CN =khx72b,OU=STUDENTS,OU=USERS,OU=SOCS,OU=FOS,OU=UNIVERSITY,DC=sepang
```

As you can see students from different faculties are in different places. 
Given an username how can I search and find if the given user is in the directory?

The `objectClass` for all the students is `'user'`.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you are searching for objects of type 'user' which are in OUs called 'STUDENTS' but otherwise have no common parent.

This cannot be done in one step (i.e. with a single LDAP query).

You must either retrieve all OUs named 'STUDENTS' and use them as Base DNs one by one, like you've already indicated.

Or you find a property that all students share (a direct group membership, for example, or a special value somewhere) and use that as the filter. This is a more dangerous approach since nothing guarantees that every student actually has the feature you rely on - some might have been not entered into AD correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Tomalak, is right, Microsoft does provide many attributes that you could use for this purpose such as "employeeType", "comment", "department", "company", "department", "divison", etc, but the problem with these is that they are not prepopulated with any information that can help you now.  You can start using one of these for future purposes, but then you must maintain that practice in order for it to be consistent.  I thing the easiest solution for you is to probably put each of the users into a group that is named similar to the OU name, which should be an really easy task if they're currently in the same OU. then once this is done you can easily create a LDAP query which will then look at the membership of that group like this:

```
((objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=STUDENTS GROUP,OU=USERS,OU=SOCS,OU=FOS,OU=UNIVERSITY,DC=sepang))
```

Please note when using the "memberOf" in an LDAP filter the search value must be a complete string to a group, and so you CAN'T use a wildcard such as: memberOf=CN=STUDENTS GROUP*).

You will still have to maintain a practice that you or someone or something (such as an automated schedule script task) which maintains the group membership to ensure that your LDAP query will be accurate.

I did see [this post](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DEV/How+to+write+a+LDAP+search+filter) which says what your trying to do is possible without having to do anything extra by ["Matching Components of Distinguished Names"](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DEV/How+to+write+a+LDAP+search+filter), but I have never seen this before and I could not get it to work. Also take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.rlmueller.net/ADOSearchTips.htm) on ADO searches to learn more about these things work

Answer (score 1):

Search for objects in an OU by setting "searchRoot" to teh LDAP path to the OU. all searches will then be confined to that OU.