# Search active directory for groups like a SQL LIKE statement

Tags: .net, active-directory

Is it possible to search active directory for a group like this:
- Give me all groups that contain the name *sample*?

In SQL I would write

```
SELECT * FROM GROUP WHERE NAME LIKE %sample%
```

I found on msdn some hints for expressions =, <= but not for a like.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.filter.aspx

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking to search for the name of the group, the link at the bottom of the page you linked tells you what to do but it does not take you directly to the page

> For more information about the LDAP search string format, see "[Search Filter Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" 
>   (I added the correct link)

Use a query like `(&(objectclass=group)(cn=*sample*))` will be what you are looking for.

If you are searching if a user is a member of a group, not just a list of all groups that match a pattern, You need to use [MemberOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032351/how-to-write-ldap-query-to-test-if-user-is-member-of-a-group) and [wildcards do not work on a `MemberOf` search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/643230/80274)

Answer (score 3):

Star acts like a wildcard in queries, so that filters like "a*" or "*a" should work.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention membership but rather just groups.